# Возможно ли вообще найти фриланс?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Здравствуйте, скоро лето, а значит освободится много рабочих мест, будет больше заказов. Но я не могу найти ни одного. Занимаюсь Android разработкой. На всех популярных сайтах то премиум аккаунт нужен, то с заказчиками не связаться, то крутые кодеры перехватывают заказы со своим обширным портфолио. Я вот уже 2 недели брожу и ничего не нахожу. Скажите, возможно ли вообще найти проект? И желательно не на раз, а вообще на все лето, клепать приложения. Или это редкость?

А то надоело уже за так кодить, а тут сунулся и на тебе.

Comment: а чего на работу не устроитесь?)

Comment: @Aliaksandr Pitkevich, я в деревне живу :)

Comment: @Flippy, самара - это деревня? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy, на данный момент живу в деревне, а в Самаре родился

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не знаю как у других, но я вот менее года назад без всякого опыта с первого же в жизни собеседования на работу устроился после отсыла резюме по 4 вакансиям, которые мне подошли по принципу - близко к дому. Всё вместе заняло 2 недели как раз... Ни с кем переспать не пришлось, да и родственником там никому, вроде, не являюсь)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow не в этой сфере мне кажется, если родственник не знает что такое ООП, то никто его туда не устроит, а если и устроит то не надолго. Тут все знания решают и опыт. Ну выше уже ответили, что человек не может строиться из-за того что в деревне живет. Как по мне, так причина, особенно если нет возможности переехать, мало ли какие ситуации в жизни. Но в такой области и удаленную постоянную работу найти я думаю не большая проблема)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Говорят, что в каком-то году в Сахаре выпал снег. Я так понимаю, что вы теперь будете утверждать, что в Сахаре постоянно покрыта снегом? Я вас конечно поздравляю, но ваше сообщение кроме вашего личного красования никакого отношения к реальности не имеет. С таким же успехом вы могли сказать, что вы выиграли в лотерею миллион.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow в этом спорить не буду) не знаю как на самом деле)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow я так сделал 2 года назад, не мог работать в офисе, зп хоть и была очень маленькая чем сейчас, но зато работа и доход был

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, не, я географ по образованию, про Сахару бы такого никогда б не сказал, вы что) Ну и не только за себя могу говорить - тут у нас на SO есть несколько человек с нуля научившихся и уже работающих вполне успешно. На работе у меня тоже народ берут. Ну и вне сайта есть знакомые программисты - всё у них ОК. Ну и статистику по отрасли смотрел как-то - вроде и места есть и з/п растёт... Так что буду считать что это у вас неполная информация) Ну и мне вот лично стабильно раз-два в месяц пишут - зовут и в офис и по удалёнке работать

Comment: Но я вот лично собираюсь бросить всё это и на себя работать - приложение запилю и буду свои копейки грести без всяких начальников и дедлайнов)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Чтобы никто ваш бред серьезно не воспринимал, я приведу простой пример. Предлагается удаленная работа в Мюнхене верстальщиком. Требования к нему просто умопомрачительные. Он на самом деле не только должен быть верстальщиком, а отлдично знать все технологии на базе JS, а также реляционные базы данных. А далее написано..."Стабильность: постоянная занятость в проектах (40 часов в неделю) с фиксированной ежемесячной зарплатой 500 — 900$;"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Программисты на это объявление подшучивали, как, например "Я таких зарплат уже давно не видел в IT области. Вот прямо сразу потянуло к вам " На что в ответ получили: " Я получила больше 180 откликов на вакансию с местного сайта о работе. Так что можно вакансию снимать)
Вам успехов в поиске работодателя, отвечающего Вашим встречным требованиям) " Вот такова реальность, а не та лапша, которую вы тут развешиваете.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ну вот чего ж вы сразу на личности-то переходите? =( Я ж не виноват что вы пользуетесь минорной версией реальности. В моей версии я наблюдаю зарплаты наших фрилансеров на подхвате. Мы сами в СПб в офисе сидим, а они не знаю откуда кодят и получают гораздо больше. А по тому какой они фиговый код фигачат их брали явно на гораздо более низкие требования. Не знаю что там на благословенном Западе, но в нашем Мордоре всё, получается, ещё лучше чем я думал) Спасибо за поднятие веры в путинско-сердюковский режим)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, может дело всё же не в радикальных различиях в уровнях интеллекта, а в различных трактовках и взглядах на мир? Вот у вас свои источники информации, а у меня свои. Выводы разные, т.к. данные разные. Может вы таки не будете сходу заявлять, что ваши выводы по вашим данным априори вернее прочих?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, сравнение с лицами голубых кровей, конечно, лестно, хотя, кмк и некорректно в данном случае. Вот даже сходил на hh и посмотрел удалённые вакансии по РФ для программистов с з\п от 45тр. Около1к выдаёт сайт. И ~6к в всего. Кмк это неплохо и есть куда устроиться. А с ростом опыта уже предложения сами пойдут.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, мы ж вроде про прогеров говорили, а не про пенсионеров? В любом случае мне надоели ваши фамильярное обращение и постоянные оскорбления и я оставлю вас наедине с вашими фантазиями о гибнущем мироздании, ведомом в пропасть злобными орками. И пойду пожалуюсь местной КровавойГэБне на ваше асоциальное поведение(

Comment: Реальность такова, что хороших инженеров  (и в техническом плане и в soft skills) днем с огнем не сыщешь. Но им нужно сначала стать. И суметь себя показать.

Comment: Отнюдь. Просто хорошие специалисты за неделю-две получат пачку офферов, выберут приятное место и уйдут с радаров. И снова ждать пока такой освободится на рынке.

Comment: Не, зачем нам рекрутинговые компании. Не надо с ними связываться, это верно. А про "ЛОЖЬ" хотелось бы какую-то аргументацию. Ну хоть контрпример.

Comment: Ну ок. Видимо, мы тут все сговорились и несем бред. Так уж вышло, коллективное помешательство. Чтобы откинуть неосторожные обобщения уточню: любой хороший Java-инженер.

Comment: Если мне не отвечают - настала пора причесывать резюме. Это игра на чужом поле, и наша задача -  "взломать" систему найма и донести информацию о себе до компетентного представителя нанимающей стороны.

Comment: Если компетентного не нашлось - оно и к лучшему. Незачем с такой организацией связываться.

Comment: По ключевым словам "Java" в Санкт Петербурге  на HH.ru сейчас 667 позиций. Понятно что там есть повторы и затесавшийся js. И просто вакансии эникейщиков. Но полсотни добротных позиций наберется.

Comment: Сбертех и вовсе сметал два года назад всех кто клавиатуру в руках держать может. Но это хуже Люксофта, право слово.

Comment: @Nofate Чтобы было много интересных разработок, нужна развитая экономика, нужно солидное инвестирование. Ни первого, ни второго в России нет, и неоткуда взяться. Тем более, что Западные фирмы, из-за санкций вынуждены сворачивать свою деятельность в России.

Comment: Ну как известно интересного для джавистов в Питере только JetBrains и Yandex. Но если покопаться - найдется еще.

Comment: Просто у нас с вами разные представления об интересных проектах. Делать IDE, которой пользуются во всем мире интересно. Писать хайлоад с жесткими ограничениями по отклику многим тоже интересно. IoT тот же - вполне. Блокчейн захайпован, но и он многим понравится.

Comment: На сегодня все. Доброй вам ночи.

Comment: Самара та еще деревня., если искать вакансии(работу) по данной тематике,  то встречаешь запросы работодателей слишком крутые.. Такое чувство что ищут билл гейтса, который будет знать всё, и везде. Запросы жесть. А зарплату платить жмотят нормальную)))

Comment: https://moikrug.ru/vacancies/1000033660 из того, что под рукой... и можно не благодарить

Answer (score 12):

Если коротко, то да, возможно.

Подробнее:

- Если нет портфолио, сделайте.
- Составьте резюме с указанием на портфолио.
- Составьте список фирм, занимающихся разработкой под Android. Затем составьте для них письмо, с описанием данной ситуации по поиску работы на лето, и отправьте его, прикрепив резюме.
- Пока ждёте ответа, найдите популярные биржи фриланса и зарегистрируйтесь на них. Добавьте информацию о себе и по возможности старайтесь сами писать заказчикам (если указаны их контактные данные).
- Также можно добавить в информацию о себе на сайтах разработчиков, которые посещаете (здесь например), заметку о том, что ищете заказы, с указанием своих контактных данных.
- Посещайте тематические группы (для разработчиков, а также "охотников за головами" headhunter-ов) в соцсетях, во многих из них есть ветки с вакансиями и предложениями о работе.
- Зарегистрируйтесь в тематических чатах (типа Slack) для разработчиков, как правило там тоже бывают каналы связанные с трудоустройством.

Ждите ответа и повышайте мастерство, пополняя портфолио.

Answer (score 11):

Вообще то типичная кривая фрилансеров выглядит так:

1. Устраиваемся на работу junior девелопером
2. Наращиваем скиллы года 3-5-7
3. Все надоедает
4. Уезжаем в деревню/Тайланд/Камбоджу/Индию
5. Занимаемся фрилансом

Иногда на п.4 люди выбиваются в топы и начинают менеджерить/продавать и проч.

А вы сразу начали с пункта 4 - оттуда у вас и проблемы.

Comment: Вы меня прям убили :(

Comment: @Flippy таки а ты хотел как? чтоб тебе внезапно миллион предложений повалило увидя учётку на ruSO? Хочешь результат - работай на него

Answer (score -3):

- нужно действовать!
  отправляйте резюме и портфолио, если не можете выбрать, то всем подряд. сделайте оговорку что только на лето.
- выберете направления которые вам нравятся. развертка пару идей в этом направлении.
- продумайте способ монетизации или улучшения.
- ходите на собеседования с распечатанным портфолио и анкетой. оставляйте их у собеседователя.
- больше уверенности в себе и меньше амбиций.
- нужна работа? получите её!